# nested select TOP 1 statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, nested, subquery

I am working on a system currently for Asset Management within our company.

The system allows users to sign in/out items on either a permenant or temporary basis.

I am working on some reporting on the system and have hit a stumbling block with returning the relevent data.

So i know that i need a nested Select TOP 1 statement within my main query but i cant get it to work.

The main query is as follows:

```
SELECT [Asset-User].ID, [Asset-User].Asset_ID, [Assets].ID, [Assets].Signed_Out, [Assets].Asset_Tag_Serial_Num, [Assets].Name_Hostname, [Assets].Type_ID, [Asset_Type].ID, [Asset_Type].Name_Model, [Asset-User].User_ID, [Company_Users].ID,  [Asset-User].Sign_Out_Date, [Asset-User].Return_Date, [Asset-User].[Perm_Signout?]
FROM [Asset-User], [Assets], [Asset_Type], [Company_Users]
WHERE ([User_ID] = '1') AND [Asset-User].Asset_ID = [Assets].ID AND [Assets].Type_ID = [Asset_Type].ID  AND [Asset-User].User_ID = [Company_Users].ID AND [Assets].Signed_Out = '1'
```

So this query returns everything that is currently marked as "Signed Out" that has ever been signed out by User 1.

Somewhere in here i need to add a nested Select TOP 1 on Asset-User.ID so that it only returns items that are marked as permanent sign outs, OR if not permanent that they have most recently been signed out by User 1.

This would then only give me a list of items currently assigned to that user and not display the Asset if someone else has signed it out since

Any help would be greatly appreciated

As per request Sample data below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o4T6bsxyO-1dGE0-FUtWFboRupcq4o4V9i2Em0_BjyU/edit?usp=sharing

First sheet shows actual results, second sheet shows roughly what should be expected

As you will see here, this user has signed out a few items multiple times (and those items may not most recently have been signed out by this user)

Its hard to get the sample data but in essence there should be no duplicate Asset_ID's in the list as only the most recent ID (sign out ID this relates to) should be displayed for each Asset_ID.

Does that help?

Thanks again

As per request here is the Schema build code that will create a sample DB to work with

```
CREATE TABLE Asset_Type
    ([ID] int, [Global_ID] int, [Name_Model] varchar(30), [Description_Spec] varchar(54))
;

INSERT INTO Asset_Type
    ([ID], [Global_ID], [Name_Model], [Description_Spec])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Dell Optiplex 3020', 'Windows 7 Professional, Intel Core i3 3.40GHz,4Gb RAM'),
    (2, 3, 'Viewsonic VA2231wa', 'Viewsonic Widescreen Monitor'),
    (3, 3, 'Samsung S24B150BL', 'Samsung LED 24" Widescreen Monitor')
;

CREATE TABLE Assets
    ([ID] int, [Asset_Tag_Serial_Num] varchar(29), [Type_ID] int, [Purchase_Date] varchar(10), [Purchase_Price] varchar(7), [Name_Hostname] varchar(36), [Signed_Out] int)
;

INSERT INTO Assets
    ([ID], [Asset_Tag_Serial_Num], [Type_ID], [Purchase_Date], [Purchase_Price], [Name_Hostname], [Signed_Out])
VALUES
    (1, '0206', 1, '2013-11-29', '323.30', 'WS0206', 1),
    (3, '0226', 2, NULL, NULL, 'Viewsonic VA2231wa - 0226', 1),
    (4, '0204', 1, '2013-11-29', '323.00', 'WS0204', 1),
    (5, '0205', 1, '2013-11-29', '323.00', 'WS0205', 1),
    (6, '0108', 1003, NULL, NULL, 'Small Office Sat Nav', 1),
    (7, '0092', 1004, NULL, NULL, 'Large Office Sat Nav', 1),
    (8, 'GWC36-DHDBC-J2MXY-H2BGY-8C79G', 1005, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'MS Office for WS0020', 1),
    (9, '0020', 1006, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'WS0020', 1),
    (10, '0173', 2, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Viewsonic VA2231wa - 0173', 1),
    (11, '0172', 1007, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Dell 19" Monitor 0172', 1),
    (12, '00104926EC6B', 1008, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Shortel 230 - EC6B', 1),
    (13, '0227', 1009, NULL, NULL, 'Blue - Yeti Mic', 0),
    (14, '0221', 1, NULL, NULL, 'WS0221', 1),
    (15, '0222', 1, '2013-11-29', '323.00', 'WS0222', 1),
    (16, '0223', 1, NULL, NULL, 'WS0223', 1),
    (17, '0220', 1, '2013-11-29', '323.00', 'WS0220', 1),
    (18, '0217', 1, '2013-11-29', '323.00', 'WS0217', 1),
    (19, '0218', 1, NULL, NULL, 'WS0218', 1),
    (20, '0219', 1, '2013-11-29', '323.00', 'WS0219', 1),
    (21, '0228', 2, NULL, NULL, 'Viewsonic VA2231wa - 0228', 1),
    (22, '0229', 1010, NULL, NULL, 'Dell 19" Monitor 0229', 1),
    (23, '00104931AA16', 1011, NULL, NULL, 'Shortel 115 - AA16', 1),
    (24, '0093 - DYTJ18X4DJ8T', 1012, NULL, NULL, 'Office IPad 3', 1),
    (25, '0095', 1013, '1900-01-01', '0.00', '320Gb External HDD', 1),
    (26, '0071', 1014, NULL, NULL, '0071 - NEC Projector', 0),
    (27, '0072', 1015, NULL, NULL, '0072 - Black Dell Projector', 0),
    (28, '0073', 1016, '1900-01-01', '0.00', '0073 - Dell Projector', 0),
    (29, '0230', 1017, '1900-01-01', '0.00', '0230 - Silver Dell Projector', 0),
    (30, '0064', 1018, NULL, NULL, 'WS0064', 0),
    (31, '0231', 1019, NULL, NULL, 'Freecom 1GB Pen - 0231', 1),
    (47, '0165', 2, NULL, NULL, 'Viewsonic VA2231wa - 0165', 1),
    (48, '0232', 1010, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Dell 19" Monitor 0232', 1),
    (49, '0233', 1010, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Dell 19" Monitor 0233', 1),
    (50, '0137', 1022, NULL, NULL, 'Viewsonic VA2248-LED - 0137', 1),
    (51, '0234', 1010, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Dell 19" Monitor 0234', 1),
    (52, '0235', 1010, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Dell 19" Monitor 0235', 1),
    (53, '0134', 1010, NULL, NULL, 'Dell 19" Monitor 0134', 0),
    (54, '0135', 1022, NULL, NULL, 'Viewsonic VA2248-LED - 0135', 1),
    (55, '0236', 3, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Samsung S24B150BL - 0236', 1),
    (56, '001049201D9A', 1008, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Shortel 230 - 1D9A', 1),
    (57, '0010492015AE', 1008, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Shortel 230 - 15AE', 1),
    (93, '0269', 1029, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'TP-Link Switch - 0269', 0),
    (94, '0058', 1030, NULL, NULL, 'WS0058', 1),
    (95, '0270', 1031, NULL, NULL, 'MeetingRoom3', 1),
    (96, '0243', 1032, NULL, NULL, 'MeetingRoom2', 1),
    (97, '0271', 1027, NULL, NULL, 'Dynamode SW80010-D Switch - 0271', 0),
    (123, '0281', 1045, '2014-07-18', '104.50', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0281', 0),
    (124, '0282', 1045, '2014-07-18', '104.50', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0282', 1),
    (125, '0283', 1045, '2014-07-18', '104.50', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0283', 0),
    (126, '0284', 1045, '2014-07-18', '104.50', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0284', 1),
    (127, '0285', 1045, '2014-07-18', '104.50', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0285', 1),
    (128, '0286', 1045, '2014-07-18', '104.50', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0286', 1),
    (129, '0287', 1045, '2014-07-18', '104.50', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0287', 1),
    (143, '0280', 1, '2014-07-03', '403.80', 'WS0280', 1),
    (144, '0296', 1, '2014-07-03', '403.80', 'WS0296', 1),
    (145, '0297', 1, '2014-07-03', '403.80', 'WS0297', 1),
    (146, '0298', 1, '2014-07-03', '403.80', 'WS0298', 1),
    (147, '0299', 1, '2014-07-03', '403.80', 'WS0299', 1),
    (148, '0052', 1036, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'WS0052', 1),
    (168, '0312', 1047, NULL, NULL, 'Epson White HD - 0312', 1),
    (169, '0201', 1049, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Ipad 4 - 0201', 0),
    (170, 'HP27J-2C496-83KXB-RGMX6-8QJQG', 1020, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'MS Office for Jonny D', 1),
    (171, '7N4QY-DFGWD-P6662-CFCHG-QYFP2', 1021, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'MS Office for WS0215 (Simeon Laptop)', 1),
    (172, '0140', 1022, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Viewsonic VA2248-LED - 0140', 1),
    (198, '0109', 1037, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'WS0109', 1),
    (199, '0324', 1052, '1900-01-01', '0.00', 'Philips 23.6" Monitor 0324', 1)
;

CREATE TABLE [Asset-User]
    ([ID] int, [Asset_ID] int, [User_ID] int, [Sign_Out_Date] datetime, [Return_Date] datetime, [Perm_Signout] int)
;

INSERT INTO [Asset-User]
    ([ID], [Asset_ID], [User_ID], [Sign_Out_Date], [Return_Date], [Perm_Signout])
VALUES
    (2, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (3, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (4, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (5, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (6, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (7, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (8, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (9, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (10, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (11, 1, 1, '2014-03-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-29 00:00:00', 0),
    (1002, 1, 1, '2014-04-01 00:00:00', '2014-04-01 00:00:00', 0),
    (1003, 1, 1, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 1)

;

CREATE TABLE Company_Users
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(14), [Domain_Username] varchar(14), [Dept] varchar(16), [Email] varchar(25), [DD_Ext] int, [Job_Title] varchar(30), [Deleted_Left] int)
;

INSERT INTO Company_Users
    ([ID], [Name], [Domain_Username], [Dept], [Email], [DD_Ext], [Job_Title], [Deleted_Left])
VALUES
    (1, 'Neil Smithson', 'Neil.Smithson', '2nd Line Support', 'neil.smithson@dezrez.com', 3041, 'Second Line Support Technician', 0)

;

CREATE TABLE Global_Types
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(13), [Description] varchar(54))
;

INSERT INTO Global_Types
    ([ID], [Name], [Description])
VALUES
    (1, 'PC', 'Desktop PC')


;
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I (for one) can't figure out what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: See edit above with a link to a spreadsheet of sample data from the DB, thanks for your help

Comment: Most people (including me) are not going to download a spreadsheet from somebody they don't know. Try sqlfiddle.com instead. Also, you really need to use ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 30 years. Additionally aliases would make this a lot easier to read.

Comment: Hi @Sean , not expecting you to download a spreadsheet, it's a viewable web page so you dont need to download anything, if i had a better rep i could upload an image of the data. Appreciate comments about Joins and Aliases, i've not done a great deal of SQL for a long long time so not that highly skilled with these things. Will have a look at the joins etc see how i get on

Comment: The advantage of using a site like sqlfiddle.com is you can upload your data in a consumable format so others can start writing queries against your data right away instead of having to setup the situation first. :)

Comment: Hi @SeanLange i will have a look at this now see how i get on

Comment: added the schema build code above to use in sqlfiddle, worth noting the query now doesnt contain the ? for the perm_signout column as wasnt playing nicely many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but will show you how you could rework this query using aliases and the (not really) newer join style.

```
SELECT au.ID
    , au.Asset_ID
    , a.ID
    , a.Signed_Out
    , a.Asset_Tag_Serial_Num
    , a.Name_Hostname
    , a.Type_ID
    , at.ID
    , at.Name_Model
    , au.User_ID
    , cu.ID
    , au.Sign_Out_Date
    , au.Return_Date
    , au.[Perm_Signout?]
FROM [Asset-User] au
join Assets a on au.Asset_ID = a.ID
join Asset_Type at on a.Type_ID = at.ID
join Company_Users cu on au.User_ID = cu.ID
WHERE au.User_ID = '1' 
    AND a.Signed_Out = '1'
```